# How do I paginate to the next page with X-ray in this case? The next button doesn't have a class or ID

Tags: html, jquery, node.js, web-scraping, x-ray

I am trying to scrape this webpage, and all the later pages too. I want x-ray to paginate through all the available pages. But the problem is the NEXT button shown in the image doesn't have any class or ID. [pagination image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bD2E.png) and here's the [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjV1V.png) for the NEXT button.
How can I paginate to the next page in this case? Thanks.

I've tried to use normal CSS selectors, but it isn't working. I don't know much about Jquery like string to formulate my selector. Is there any resources available to help me understand how I can write the selector? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.